# Rails 3.2: rake 10.0.3 required

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When executing any rake operation, I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/home/cristi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup'
/home/cristi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/cristi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.3/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/home/cristi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/cristi/code/kodion/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/cristi/code/kodion/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/cristi/code/kodion/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am not sure what I can do to solve this. `bundle exec` doesn't solve anything.

Comment: What is the error you get when you do `bundle exec rake some:task` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You either need to run the command in the context of the bundle (recommended):

```
> bundle exec rake db:version
```

Or you need to uninstall the offending rake gem version.

```
> gem uninstall rake
>  # pick version 10.1.0 from the offered choices.
```

Comment: Not sure why this was happening, but adding bundle exec to the beginning of the command like: ```bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear``` fixed for me, thanks. That error message should be just a bit more decriptive!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same type of error. Try this:

> bundle exec rake db:migrate